# No Azure subscriptions in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I was successfully publishing on different Azure websites for a few weeks but all of a sudden, today, it failed with the following error:

```
Error   1   Web deployment task failed. (Impossible d'exécuter la demande sur l'URL d'agent distant 'https://xxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xxxxxxxx'.)

Impossible d'exécuter la demande sur l'URL d'agent distant 'https://xxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=xxxxxxxx'.
The operation has timed out     0   0   xxxxxxxx.Web
```

I opened the publish settings in Visual Studio and could not validate any connection...
So I went to the Profile tab, clicked on "Microsoft Azure Websites" publish target, signed out and signed in again, only to be told that "no Azure subscriptions were added".

If I log into the Azure portal in Chrome, everything is OK and I can see all my subscriptions (I'm the administrator).

Although, a colleague of mine (co-administrator) tried to sign in in my Visual Studio and got the same treatment: "No Azure subscriptions were added."

And of course, if he logs in his browser, everything is fine. And he can also sign in in his Visual Studio.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history

Comment: Thanks but no incident occured on the date of my problem. And my problem is still going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the browsing history, including (and especially) cookies in Internet Explorer did the trick.
I can now connect again to my Azure account.